# Use solid color for highlighted words in pdf.js

Tags: css, pdf.js

I want to change the highlight color used by pdf.js

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Press Ctrl + F and find any word any in thid doc

I can do that by changing color in pdf js's style file.

```
.textLayer .highlight.selected {
    background-color: rgb(0, 100, 0);
}
```

I would like this color to be non-transparent. if you see highlighted words is transparent.

I get the reason for making it transparent is so that underlying pdf content is visible. Pdf.js just renders transparent text over the original pdf content. It uses this transparent text for searching and highlighting.

Is there anyway I can highlight the word in a solid color?

Answer (score 0):

In viewer.css the class textLayer, you can change the opacity.  To make it solid, you can remove opacity or set to 1,  but you will not be able to see the text.  I find 0.4 looks pretty good

```
.textLayer {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     opacity: 1; /* 0.4 looks nice, but 1 answers your question */
 }
```

Comment: Being able to see the selected text is kinda important :\